# Allow users to SELECT from dynamic SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, dynamic-sql

I've been looking at the DBMS_SQL package in Oracle and trying to see if there is a way to create a view or something that users can select from to see the results of a dynamic SQL query.

I have a test procedure based on the documentation:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_dyn_sql AS
  cursor_name INTEGER;
  rows_processed INTEGER;
  l_query LONG;
BEGIN
  l_query := 'SELECT SYSDATE AS the_date, ''ABC'' AS the_string, 1 AS the_int FROM dual';  
  cursor_name := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
  DBMS_SQL.PARSE(cursor_name, l_query, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
  rows_processed := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(cursor_name);
  DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(cursor_name);      
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(cursor_name);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('ERROR');
END;
```

But this just executes the statement and does not return anything. What I'd like is a view so a user can just do a `SELECT the_date FROM some_view` and get the results.  I will not know the names or number of columns in advance, so that's why I'm after a dynamic SQL solution.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to do that.  That's not what view are really for.  You could maybe create a function that returns a table somehow?  See [this](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions.php) example of a table function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> " I will not know the names or number of columns in advance, so that's
>   why I'm after a dynamic SQL solution"

That's pretty hard to implement in SQL: SQL is all about the data structures, and it really expects the columns to exist up front.  So you cannot build a VIEW on a mutable data structure.

You can implement a function which returns a ref cursor.  This is a pointer to a data structure which can be interpreted by a client, say as a JDBC ResultSet.

Here's an example function which takes a table name and column name, assembles the query and returns its result set.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_dyn_sql 
  (tab_name in varchar2
   , col_name in varchar2)
  return  sys_refcursor
AS
  return_value sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
  open return_value for
    'SELECT SYSDATE AS the_date, '||col_name||' FROM '||tab_name;  
  return return_value;
END;
/
```

The output is not very elegant in SQL*Plus but you get the idea.

```
SQL> select test_dyn_sql ('EMP', 'NAME') from dual;

TEST_DYN_SQL('EMP','
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

THE_DATE  NAME
--------- ------------------------------
03-APR-15 FOX IN SOCKS
03-APR-15 MR KNOX
03-APR-15 DAISY-HEAD MAYZIE


SQL>
```

I suggest you stick with Native Dynamic SQL (that is, `execute immediate`) as much as possible: as you can see, it's really simple compared to DBMS_SQL.  Only reach for DBMS_SQL when you have some extremely complicated requirement.

---

I appreciate this may not be the solution form you're looking for.  If that is the case please *edit your question* to provide more details about the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your code to return the value of **rows_processed** variable use the code below which will return 0.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_dyn_sql(asd INTEGER) RETURN INTEGER AS
      cursor_name INTEGER;
      rows_processed INTEGER;
      l_query LONG;
    BEGIN
      l_query := 'SELECT SYSDATE AS the_date, ''ABC'' AS the_string, 1 AS the_int FROM dual';  
      cursor_name := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
      DBMS_SQL.PARSE(cursor_name, l_query, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
      rows_processed := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(cursor_name);
      DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(cursor_name);      
      RETURN rows_processed;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(cursor_name);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('ERROR');
        RETURN 0;
    END;
```

This is how you call the function from plsql

```
DECLARE
  rows_precessed INTEGER;
BEGIN
  rows_precessed := test_dyn_sqll(0);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(rows_precessed);
END;
```